# Processing PApplet loading image not working

Tags: java, processing, textures, loadimage

I'm using the `processing.core.PApplet` library in a simple Java Project. 
I load multiple images in the `setting` function and I tried to draw them in the `draw` function but oddly the textures doesn't appear ?

There is the code I use to load them :

```java
public void init() throws FileNotFoundException { // this get executed in the 'setting' function of my sketch
    Registry.register(getImage("void"), "void");
}

public processing.core.PImage getImage(String name) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String path = "src\\main\\resources\\blocks\\textures\\" + name + ".png";
    File file = new File(path);

    if(file.exists()) {
        Logger.info("Texture " + file.getAbsolutePath() + " found.", "TextureMapping");
        return sketch.loadImage(path);
    } else {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("File " + file.getAbsolutePath() + " not found." );
    }
}
```

And the code I use to draw one of them :

```java
// I create and draw a new cube in the 'draw' function of my sketch
// But it appears without any texture
public Cube(processing.core.PApplet sketch, BlockPos pos, @NotNull Block block) { 
    this.sketch = sketch;
    this.block = block;
    position = pos;
    texture = Registry.getTextures().get("minecraft:void");
    texture.loadPixels();
}

public void draw() {
    sketch.pushMatrix();
    sketch.translate(position.getX(), position.getY(), position.getZ());
    sketch.box(10);
    sketch.texture(texture); // Doin' nothing
    sketch.popMatrix();
}
```

And the file are there, my `Logger` say that they are found, I get no error, and yet the texture has all the properties of an PImage ?

And second oddly thing : 
Before the `draw` method, I do this in the `draw` function :

```java
sketch.image(Registry.getTextures().get("minecraft:void"), 10, 10);
```

And there, the image loads perfectly ???

*yes I'm doin' a Minecraft clone*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found !

The `texture()` is only working when runned between the `preDraw()` and `postDraw()` functions, but the `box()` function has these steps into it, so it cannot work, you have to create a cube using Vertex. 
Processing offers us an example to make it [there](https://processing.org/examples/texturecube.html) !

What I did to customize this example is a `Box` class that create vertex, a size can be set also, there it is :

```java
public class Box {
    private final PApplet sketch;
    private final int scale;

    public Box(PApplet sketch, int scale) {
        this.sketch = sketch;
        this.scale = scale;
    }

    public void generateVertex(PImage texture) {
        sketch.scale(scale);
        sketch.beginShape(sketch.QUADS);
        sketch.texture(texture);

        // +Z "front" face
        sketch.vertex(-1, -1, 1, 0, 0);
        sketch.vertex(1, -1, 1, 1, 0);
        sketch.vertex(1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
        sketch.vertex(-1, 1, 1, 0, 1);

        // -Z "back" face
        sketch.vertex(1, -1, -1, 0, 0);
        sketch.vertex(-1, -1, -1, 1, 0);
        sketch.vertex(-1, 1, -1, 1, 1);
        sketch.vertex(1, 1, -1, 0, 1);

        // +Y "bottom" face
        sketch.vertex(-1, 1, 1, 0, 0);
        sketch.vertex(1, 1, 1, 1, 0);
        sketch.vertex(1, 1, -1, 1, 1);
        sketch.vertex(-1, 1, -1, 0, 1);

        // -Y "top" face
        sketch.vertex(-1, -1, -1, 0, 0);
        sketch.vertex(1, -1, -1, 1, 0);
        sketch.vertex(1, -1, 1, 1, 1);
        sketch.vertex(-1, -1, 1, 0, 1);

        // +X "right" face
        sketch.vertex(1, -1, 1, 0, 0);
        sketch.vertex(1, -1, -1, 1, 0);
        sketch.vertex(1, 1, -1, 1, 1);
        sketch.vertex(1, 1, 1, 0, 1);

        // -X "left" face
        sketch.vertex(-1, -1, -1, 0, 0);
        sketch.vertex(-1, -1, 1, 1, 0);
        sketch.vertex(-1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
        sketch.vertex(-1, 1, -1, 0, 1);

        sketch.endShape();
    }

    public int getScale() {
        return scale;
    }
}
```

And this solve perfectly my problem, now I have a cube with textures !